# Webhook doesn't received any message

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm following your guide posted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot) to create a custom bot. I use ngrok to expose my webhook running on localhost to the Internet. It's OK to access the webhook by browser or curl. But when bot is mentioned (@botname), the webhook doesn't got any messages. What could be wrong?

Comment: More information would be very valuable. Can you show some examples of a) your webhook source code, and/or b) how you are invoking it?

In particular I'm wondering how you are accessing your endpoint via the browser. Browsers are good at doing HTTP GETs but the custom bot is expecting an HTTP POST so I'm wondering if that's the problem. But that's just speculation - more information is needed to answer your question.

Comment: I actually don't run a "real" webhook, just start ngrok by the command "$ ngrok http 8080" to get a forwarding URL, for example,  https://07ea62a7.ngrok.io. Then I use it as my webhook. ngrok captures and logs any HTTP(S) sent to the webhook. I expected MS Teams sends messages to ngrok (of course, ngrok will fail to forward to "real" webhook). But the log showed nothing.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me. I typed `ngrok http 8080` and used the https URL as the callback URL for the webhook, sent a message to @TestBot, and this is what appeared in the ngrok debugger:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHfDF.png

Comment: It's strange! After your comment, I repeat what I did and it works! Thanks @BillBliss-MSFT for your supporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a transient problem - it works now for both OP and myself.